# symfony2 after submit the values changed

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

Good morning ,

I selected a row from database to edit it

```
$object_before_edit=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyBundle:MyClass')->find($object_id);

$form = $this->createForm(new MyClassType(), $object_before_edit);

$form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {

        // I modified this 2 fields in form 
        dump($form['fielda']->getData()) . "<br/>";// line 1
        dump($form['fieldb']->getData()). "<br/>";// line 2

        // but here i want to see the object in the database before doing
        // persist and flush

        dump($object_before_edit->getFielda()) . "<br/>";// line 3
        dump($object_before_edit->getFieldb());// line 4
        die();

}
```

in my database :

fielda = 1

fieldb = 2

i change it in form :

fielda = 3

fieldb = 4

so in the dump i saw :

line 1 : 3 // its logic

line 2 : 4 // its logic

**line 3 : 3 // Why ???**

**line 4 : 4 // why ???**

normally the code display the value in the DB not in the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're writing this line:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyClassType(), $object_before_edit);
```

You're binding the form to a reference to the object in the second parameter. Symfony forms define a mapping between the form and the underlying object, which gets accessed and modified when the form is handled (`$form->handleRequest($request);`).

If you want to keep the original values, you might want to clone the original object:

```
$object = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyBundle:MyClass')->find($object_id);
$originalObject = clone $object;
$form = $this->createForm(new MyClassType(), $object);

$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    dump($form['fielda']->getData()) . "<br/>";// 3
    dump($form['fieldb']->getData()). "<br/>";// 4

    dump($originalObject->getFielda()) . "<br/>";// 1
    dump($originalObject->getFieldb());// 2
    die();
}
```

Be careful when doing things like this. Make sure that the EntityManager does not persist the cloned object.